# Handlebars/Ember.Checkbox - 2 bound checkboxes, one checked on false

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on an RSVP form in an app, and I'm trying to figure out how to have two checkboxes mirror each other, when one is checked the other is not. Right now, my approach has been to have each checkbox bound to the `isComing` property, with one being checked on `!isComing`, but it's not working that way.

Here's what I tried:

HTML:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars'>
<label>I&#39;m coming!</label>
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isComing"}}
<label>I can&#39;t make it.</label>
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="!isComing"}}

{{#if isComing}}
<p>The rest of the form will be here.</p>
{{/if}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isComing: false
});
```

This doesn't work. The first checkbox works fine, but the second checkbox is completely unaffected. Clearly, `!isComing` is not allowed...

This would be trivial to do in jQuery, and I thought about created a computed property that the second checkbox is bound to and that listens to `isComing`, but those don't seem like the **right** way.

Is there an easier way to do this with Handlebars or Ember? [Here's the fiddle if you want to experiment.](http://jsfiddle.net/mmerkes/3aZzn/)

Comment: Are you intentionally not using a radio button?  Just curious

Comment: No, a radio button would be fine. I didn't use one because there isn't an Ember version of it, but I suppose it wouldn't be too hard to write my own view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a radio button, then I'd use this dude's implementation (http://thoughts.z-dev.org/2013/07/04/radio-buttons-in-ember-js/), simple and clean

```
App.RadioButton = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName : "input",
    type : "radio",
    attributeBindings : [ "name", "type", "value", "checked:checked:" ],
    click : function() {
        this.set("selection", this.$().val())
    },
    checked : function() {
        return this.get("value") == this.get("selection");   
    }.property()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3aZzn/2/

That being said, Adam's answer is just as good if you don't mind one being checked up front.

Comment: Thanks! And you used -1 as the initial `isComing` value, which is the same as using `null`?

Comment: yeah for sure, I have old habits of using -1 sometimes get past QA.

Comment: I'm experiencing one more problem. My isComing is an attribute in my model as I want to save it. Everything works great, except that isComing is not being sent in the POST request. Any thoughts why it's in the model and appears to be working fine, but isn't being sent to the server?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think to do this is through a computedProperty. I forked your jsfiddle to show how it's working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmkes/1/). You would write your controller like this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isComing: false,
    isntComing: function(key, value) {
        if (arguments.length == 2) {
            this.set('isComing', !value);
        }
        return !(this.get('isComing'));
    }.property('isComing')
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great, and I didn't realize that these values were passed into the function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as "not" operator in Handlebars. You need to bind the state of the second checkbox to some other property. It could be done like this:
Template

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isComing"}}
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isNotComing"}}
```

JS

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isComing: false,
    isNotComing: Em.computed.not('isComing')
});
```

Comment: Petr the computed isn't a two way binding, changing isNotComing won't disable isComing

Comment: @kingpin2k You're right. Thanks for pointing this out. Sorry for misunderstanding the question a bit. For the described behaviour of the checkboxes I agree with an answer Adam posted.